# App no longer opening after iOS6 migration

Tags: ios6, upgrade

I have an app in the App Store and I've gotten reports from several users worldwide that the app, mostly after upgrading to iOS 6, no longer works. The app uses the following frameworks:

- QuickLook
- MessageUI
- MobileCoreServices
- QuartzCore
- CoreData
- UIKit
- Foundation
- CoreGraphics

So far, the only possible lead I have found is the change in **screen rotation** from iOS 5 to iOS 6, but sources indicate that this only takes effect when building the app with the iOS 6 SDK.

I have restored my iPad 3 to factory settings (iOS 6.01) and re-downloaded the app from the App Store, but the app is working fine. Any idea what to look for?

Comment: Have you had any crash reports in, either via iTunes Connect or a third party framework if you're using one?

Comment: yes, but to be honest, can't interpret it well. In iTunes connect it shows: 1.
CoreFoundation: +[__NSArrayI __new:::]
100% of submitted crashes

Comment: this is the report, just downloaded:


Incident Identifier: 327FC5F3-FAA2-4B62-B759-6CF281C78A90
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:         MisRecetas [3243]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2E644CB8-7B2D-40A1-9697-6985227C3940/MisRecetas.app/MisRecetas
Identifier:      MisRecetas
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-27 17:25:57.804 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0a0a0a12
Crashed Thread:  0

Comment: Had you made any changes to core data?